# delete very, very similar rows in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

In PHPMYAdmin, i am running a web crawler. the web crawler occasionally picks up the same urls. In the web crawler, it has indexed thousands of links, and i don't want duplicate links. is there a way to delete similar rows in SQL (the only difference being the id field)

Comment: Is the `id` field an auto-incremented INT field?

Comment: yes it is an auto-incremented field

Answer (score 1):

You can `DELETE` all URLs except the one with the maximum id (most recent):

```
DELETE    a 
FROM      tbl a
LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT   MAX(id) AS id 
          FROM     tbl 
          GROUP BY url
          ) b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE     b.id IS NULL
```

After you do this, it might be a good idea to set up a unique constraint on the url field:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD UNIQUE idx_unique_url (url);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your table is named `the_table` and its fields are `id` (a unique field) and `url`, then you can write:

```
DELETE
  FROM the_table
 WHERE id NOT IN
        ( SELECT *
            FROM ( SELECT MIN(id)
                     FROM the_table
                    GROUP BY url
                 ) t
        )
;
```

(If you have other fields as well, and only want to delete rows where *all* fields are identical except `id`, then just add those fields to the `GROUP BY` clause along with `url`.)

Comment: Just FYI, you cannot reference the same table in a subquery in a DELETE operation. It will throw this error: `#1093 - You can't specify target table 'the_table' for update in FROM clause`.

Comment: @ZaneBien: Oh, I forgot about that. Darn MySQL. Fixed now, thank you. :-)

Comment: doesnt do what i ask, i asked to delete duplicate data what was not part of the id tag

Comment: @user1582899: Can you elaborate on the difference between what this does and what you want?